# Can you split a string in PHP with a regex, but easily get the matched string which split the string?

Tags: php, regex

My string looks like so

> February 2009
>
> bla bla
>
> March 2009
>
> doo daa bla lbla
>
> Septemer 2009

So I wrote this regex to split it up into months (which is what I want to do first, I think)

```
$regex = '/(.*)\s(\d){4}/i';
```

This matches them perfectly, except it throws away the actual string they were split on .. i.e. I want that information (as in February 2009, March 2009 etc)

I've tried mucking around with the `preg_split()` flags, but could not get what I wanted.

Should I be using a different approach? Is there an easy to split text via a regex but keep the text that was actually there?

Come to think of it, I could probably use `preg_match_all()' here... I hope I just didn't answer my own question in the answer - I'm going to post anyway to see what the community thinks.

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure what the desired output is (and I think the answerers are a bit divided on the interpretation of your requirements as well).  Please improve your question by providing the input as a variable declaration and provide your exact desired output array.

Comment: Is this the desired result? https://3v4l.org/pvRNa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the splitting string into its own capture group. So given your example,

```
$regex = '/(.*)\s(\d){4}/';
```

with a few modifications becomes:

```
$regex = '/(.+?)(\s)(\d{4})/';
```

If your matches array is called "$matches", $matches[0] will contain the whole match, $matches[1] the month, $matches[2] the splitting string, and $matches[3] the year.

Answer (score 2):

preg_split's 4th option is the flags:

http://www.php.net/preg-split

> `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` If this
> flag is set, parenthesized expression
> in the delimiter pattern will be
> captured and returned as well.

```
$a = preg_split('/(.*\s\d{4})/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($a);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

    [1] => February 2009
    [2] => 
bla bla

    [3] => March 2009
    [4] => 
doo daa bla lbla

    [5] => Septemer 2009
    [6] => 

)
```

So that's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

it looks that it works even without the non greedy modifier '?'

```
preg_match('/(.*)\s(\d{4})/', "Month 2009", $a);
```

(i wonder why as (.*) should match the whole string, isn't it ?)

Comment: Initially, `(.*)` consumes the whole rest of the string, but that leaves nothing for the rest of the regex to match. So it starts backtracking--"giving back" the most recently matched characters--until it becomes possible for `\s(\d{4})` to match (or until it gets back to the starting point and gives up). If a regex with a greedy quantifier matches a given string, the same regex with a non-greedy quantifier is guaranteed to match it, too (and vice-versa).

Comment: `.*` doesn't match the entire input string because `.` doesn't match newlines, there is no `s` pattern modifier, and the input is on multiple lines.  If the `s` modifier was added, then a lazy quantifier would be called for.